# Jquery - put text in a parent div with a class

Tags: jquery, append

I am using

```
function example_append() {
  $('#containment').append($('#example-textarea').val());
}
```

This is throwing the text I put in the form field in to the div #containment. I'd like to place the value of the form field into the containment div, but also have it wrapped in a div with a class name so I can style it. Is this possible?

Also, the user inserts the text via the form field and it gets thrown into that div, how could I remove that string of text if the user wants to start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two functions should do what you're looking for.  Just bind `reset_text` to a button or text on click.

**edit**  Added event bind for clearing text.

```
function example_append() {
   $('#containment').append(
      $('<div />').addClass('className').text($('#example-textarea').val())
   );
}

$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#example_button').on('click', reset_text );
});

function reset_text() {
   $('#example-textarea').val('');
   $('.className').remove():
}
```

Comment: I get this error when trying that invalid label
[Break On This Error]  

       $('.user-text').remove():

demo.html (line 107, col 26)

Comment: I see what was wrong now it had a colon instead of a break key. Many thanks for the help!!

Comment: do you know why I would get this error even though I changed that colon? remove_text is not defined

Comment: the function was called reset_text(), did you change the name of the second function?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this :

```
var div = $('#example-textarea').val();
$('#containment').append(div.wrap('<div class="new" />'));
```

that wraps the value in a div with class "new"
and to remove the textarea value, just do this :

```
$('#example-textarea').val('')
```

Comment: that removed it from the form field but I need something to remove the div that was inserted in from the first function. I tried just changing to the class but nothing happens                                                                                                                                     $('.user-text').val('')